# Answering a question that wasn't asked

Tags: discussion, answers

If I stumble across a question whose title asks for something, "why isn't my X working in Y language", and I look in, and they explain their problem; they say what they're trying to do, they give their problem, give their code... and their code won't do what they're trying to do, but *not* because of the issue that they're bringing up.

The question making me ask is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35689065/why-wont-my-while-loop-break-the-scanner-goes-on-longer-than-i-want-it-to), where the user asks why their while loop prints out the whole text file instead of one line. Their code ultimately had a problem in a different piece of code, and the posted snippet wasn't being run.

However, in looking at the code that *was* posted, I see that what they *intend* to do wouldn't even be completed by their program even if their file was interacting properly with the program.

Is it bad to answer this question explaining the problem I see, even though it isn't what's asked? Or should I only answer the question proposed in the title?